# moment invalid date in firefox, safari

Tags: javascript, date, firefox, momentjs

I am using moment Javascript plugin to format the date,it works in chrome but not in firefox nor Safari.

here is the code I am using:

```
var date = new Date(deadline.value);
alert(date); //prints out "Sat Feb 21 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)"

deadline.value = moment(date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate()).format();
alert(deadline.value); //prints "Invalid date"
```

Comment: Which browser does it not work in? Your question states "it works in chrome but not in firefox nor chrome". Did you mean Safari?

Comment: You would need to pad the month for that format "2015-02-20"

Comment: edited the question - it works in chrome :) does not work in safari or firefox

Comment: is there an easy way of changing the month format with moment or not?

Answer (score 2):

The moment docs (see [parsing](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/)) note browser support for parsing strings is inconsistent. This [chart](http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html) shows that only the UTC version of "YYYY-MM-DD" is supported in Firefox (v4+) currently.

UTC: `2009-07-12`

Local: `2009-7-12`

So, you need to pad the month with a zero for the format to be valid.

Comment: do you know if there is an easy way of changing a 'feb' into an '02'? I need the 'feb' for design as that is what the user sees.

Comment: Take a look at the format codes within the [Moment documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).